# Why won't both Jquery lines execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this code below, all divs other than the select are "display: none" (in CSS) to start.  When someone chooses an option from the Select dropdown, the jquery executes but in the "typeChosen()" function, only the first line executes (to show all divs with the class of "always").  The code to see if "size" was in the class and if so, display all divs with a class of "size" isn't executing.

Basically, if one of the options with "size" in the class is chosen, all 4 divs at the bottom should appear.  If an option WITHOUT "size" in the class is choses, then only the first 3 divs would show.

Do I have to do something differently in the Jquery to have more than one line execute?  I could be wrong, but it seems like it's just doing the first line and stopping.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#typeofrequest").change(function () {
        typeChosen();
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

});
function typeChosen() {
    $(".always").show();
    $('#typeofrequest').on( 'change', function( e ) {
      if( $(this).find('option:selected').hasClass("size") )
          $('div.size').show();
      else
          $('div.size').hide();
     });
}



        <form action="process-request.php" method="post">
  <select id="typeofrequest" name="type">
    <option value="">PLEASE SELECT</option>
    <option value="email" class="size">LOGsdfgdfgsdgdfgt</option>
    <option value="email" class="size">LOGO - Logo request</option>
    <option value="email" class="size">EMAIL - Graphic</option>
    <option value="social" class="size">SOCIAL MEDIA - Graphic</option>
    <option value="" class="size">LANDING PAGE - Graphic</option>
    <option value="" class="size">LANDING PAGE - Other</option>
    <option value="" class="size">EVENTS - Brochure</option>
    <option value="" class="size">EVENTS - Signage</option>
    <option value="" class="size">EVENTS - Other</option>
    <option value="print" class="size bleed">ADS - Print Ad</option>
    <option value="" class="size">ADS - Digital Ads for Corporate</option>
    <option value="" class="size">ADS - Digital Ads for Clients</option>
    <option value="" class="size">COLLATERAL - Sell Sheet</option>
    <option value="" class="size">COLLATERAL - Case Study</option>
    <option value="" class="size">COLLATERAL - Brochure/Booklet</option>
    <option value="" class="size">COLLATERAL - E-Book</option>
    <option value="">WEBSITES - Copy change</option>
    <option value="">WEBSITES - Add Press Release</option>
    <option value="">WEBSITES - Upload a document</option>
    <option value="" class="size">WEBSITES - Imagery change</option>
    <option value="">WEBSITES - New page(s)</option>
    <option value="">WEBSITES - Brand new website</option>
    <option value="">WEBSITES - Report an issue</option>
    <option value="">CULTURE -Shirt Design</option>
    <option value="">GENERAL QUESTION</option>  <!--this should NOT send email-to-case -->
    <option value="" class="size">Random/Miscellaneous graphic</option>
    <option value="">OTHER</option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <br/>


  <div class="always"> Priority Level?
    <label for="priorityurgent">Urgent</label>
    <input type="radio" id="priorityurgent" name="priority" value="urgent" >
    <label for="priorityqueue">Put in queue</label>
    <input type="radio" id="priorityqueue" name="priority" value="queue" checked >
    </div>
  <div class="always">Due Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Click to pop-up calendar">
  </div>
  <div class="always"> Enter any additional information about timing<br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter additional info regarding timing..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="size"> Size (w x h):
    <input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="WxH" required />
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code works for me, https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yjdczu6y/. What errors are you getting? And why are you setting up an event handler inside the function?

Comment: $("#typeofrequest").change(function () {   &   $('#typeofrequest').on( 'change', function( e ) { it is almost same. Not sure what is the use of separately doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `document.ready` already has assigned the event, so your `typeChosen` doesn't need to

```
function typeChosen(thisObj) {
    $(".always").show();
      if( $(thisObj).find('option:selected').hasClass("size") )
          $('div.size').show();
      else
          $('div.size').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#typeofrequest").change(function () {
        typeChosen(this);
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: That's it! You beat me up :)

Comment: Are we looking at the same question?  It *is* in `document.ready`

Comment: Am I missing something? How does `#typeofrequest` not exist?

Comment: @Archer I think his `document.ready()` is already closed. Just checked it via http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @j08691 your fiddle invokes this method in `onload` event, but that is not what OP indicates when he explicitly uses a `document.ready`

Comment: The first line of code inside `document.ready` assigns the event handler.

Comment: Updated the fiddle, same result.

Comment: @j08691 I don't think OP needs to assign the event handler again via `on` since it has been defined already in `document.ready`.

Comment: You should delete everything you first posted above your edit. The OP's code is correct although his logic is wrong. The crux of his issue is that he's setting up a second event handler in his function so it won't get triggered until after the first change. And another problem with the way he set it up is that he's adding event handlers on every change.

Comment: So basically you update your incorrect answer, to make it the same as mine, yeah?

Comment: @Archer it is not really same as yours, although my original one wasn't correct.

Comment: No - my mistake.  Yours finds the element and passes it as a parameter, where mine finds the element within the function.  They're vastly different smh

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback, this solution worked and I appreciate the JSFiddle demos as well...definitely helping me learn so I don't do silly things like assign event twice